# Cast Exception in sorting date method

Tags: java, treemap

I have a list "unSortedDateList" in which dates are stored as CSV. 
dates are stored in following format **(MM/dd/yyyy)
1/10/2012, 2/10/2011, 1/9/2011** **(note: DATES ARE STORE as COMMA SEPERATED VALUE)**

I have written a function which takes these dates from the list and sort them in ASC and store in sortedList.

```
 TreeMap<Date, Date> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Date, Date>();

    for (Date theDate : unSortedDateList) 
    {
      sortedMap.put(theDate.getTime(), theDate);
    }
    List<Date> sortedList = (List<Date>) sortedMap.values();
```

The program is throwing a cast exception.

Can you please help me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Stacktrace? Have you parsed the data into Date types? Then you could use Collections.sort(unsortedDateList)

Comment: i believe theDate.getTime() returns a long

Comment: And TreeMap.values() doesn't return a List. It returns a Collection. Create a new List from the collection if you want, but don't cast.

Comment: Collections.sort(unsortedDateList) worked :), Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not sort the list with

```
Collections.sort(unsortedDateList)
```

directly?

Answer (score 2):

You are putting a long value in a date field. That has to crash.

```
sortedMap.put(theDate.getTime(), theDate); //getTime() is long
```

but your map is `Date`

```
TreeMap<Date, Date> sortedMap
```

Comment: Correct, I have changed it to theDate. Still its throwing an exception.

Comment: why does people upvote this when it is obviously not the key point of the question?

Comment: @STT LCU 
Its not about scoring point. Its about identifying problems ( even not asked) in the code.

Comment: i haven't even mentioned points, it's just that this answer isn't related to the question, even if it is correct indeed in its own scope.

Answer (score 1):

quoting the java documentation for SE6:

> values() returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map.

It does not return a List: a list is a Collection but the reverse is not necessarily true.

EDIT: next time please provide a stacktrace and the exact row where the error occurs.